# Printing information in the command window while running a sqlcmd process in a c# program

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd, process, sqlcmd

I run an update process from my c# wpf program like this:

```
Process sql = Process.Start("sqlcmd.exe", param);
sql.WaitForExit(1200000);
```

The variable param is build from user input in the ui, here is a example:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d mydatabase -v db_src = "db\file.bak" -i db\update.sql -o "\log\log_update.txt"
```

Now the black cmd window opens and runs for a while (1-5 minutes). On some machines the white curos blinks. What I want is that something like `"Please wait... & "` is printed on the cmd window.

I've tried different approaces but the sqlmd erases everything. Like putting a `echo Please wait...` in front of param.

Displaying something in the c# program is also difficult because while the process runs, the program is frozen. But if anyone knows a solution which makes it possible to display a message in the program this would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.WaitForExit()` blocks your current application thread. Instead you should just start the process in the background, and wait for the `Exited` event.

To quote [MSDN - see the remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.8):

> WaitForExit() makes the current thread wait until the associated
>   process terminates. It should be called after all other methods are
>   called on the process. To avoid blocking the current thread, use the
>   Exited event.

If your thread isn't blocked you can write progress/status messages that'll actually appear.